# Rails how to create a delayed job for a rake taks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

How do I create a delayed job for a rake task that should run every 15 minutes?

Comment: What platform are you on?  I have tasks (on a windows box) that run every day using the Windows Scheduler.  Another box (Linux) I use is taking advantage of cron to run daily jobs.

Comment: I am using heroku, therefor I need a delayed job

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give it a try: https://github.com/defunkt/resque

Answer (score 0):

I am using Resque + Redis with Heroku. Delayed job is also very much supported on their cloud service.

**In lib/tasks/cron.rb**

```
desc "This task is called by the Heroku cron add-on"
task :cron => :environment do

  def resubmit_pending_jobs
    Resque.enqueue(SomeJob, job.id)
  end
end
```

One way I can think of is by using the cron [addon](http://addons.heroku.com/cron) offered by Heroku which does it every hour (not 15 mins). Perhaps the above code block can assist you in finding a similar implementation for Delayed Job.

In the case you are interested in getting Resque setup with RedisToGo and Heroku, please consult this [guide](http://blog.redistogo.com/2010/07/26/resque-with-redis-to-go/).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SimpleWorker. It's a cloud-based background processing / worker queue for Ruby apps. It's an add-on for Heroku.

You create worker classes in your code and the queue up jobs to run right away or run later -- one time or on a recurring schedule.

```
  worker = SomeWorker.new
  # Set attributes for worker to use here
  worker.schedule(:start_at => 1.minute, :run_every => 900)
```